# Sum Up Values from the Same Date In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, countif

I have a sheet that I am using to track wordcount over multiple writing projects. I'd like to have it automatically add up the words I've written that day. I write in multiple sessions, and each session is its own row on the sheet.

I continue to add onto the sheet during the month, so using DATE won't work unless I want to manually change the formula every time a new day starts. I'd really appreciate whatever help could be given.

Here is the link to the sheet--this one is a copy, so feel free to poke around as needed and don't worry about messing it up :) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNrJzSDpfTRuvZSRpt7BQn0HfA2mdhZzTym2DqNlXZU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete all in column `I` and use in row 1:

```
={"Daily Total"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, A2:A, ), QUERY({A2:A, H2:H}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]